# Restructuring the data in an object hierarchically retrieved from the database

Tags: java, database, data-structures, parent-child, recursive-datastructures

This is my object Structure

```
-List
  -ObjectA(Id=01)
    -SubList
      -ObjectA(Id=01-01)
      -ObjectA(Id=01-02)
        -SubList
          -ObjectA(Id=01-02-01)

  -ObjectA(Id=02)
    -SubList
      -ObjectA(Id=02-01)
```

List Has ObjectA which in turn has SubList containing same Object(ObjectA) with other attributes as well. Id number conveys 01 as Parent Object, 01-01 as First Sub Object in the object 01 and so on

Problem is I'm able to save this data using recursion, but while retrieving from database all these sub objects are saved in different rows in the same table and i'm getting it as a list. What is the best way to restructure the data retrieved as per the Object hierarchy using its Id Number.

Comment: If you have a recursive hierarchy, then handling this in the database might be the best thing to do.

Comment: what is the best way to handle in database?

Comment: If your table has a column(s) for parent child relationship, then there are a ton of answers on SO for how to generate the output you want.

Comment: you mean like multiple tables for different level with parent id as foreign key?

Comment: No, I have in mind a single table which maintains the recursive hierarchy.

Comment: how it can be implemented?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some sample data.  Then, we can go from there.  At first site, this looks like something which might be handled best in the DB.